Why can I not pass parameters into another screen with react tabs navigation?
When I try and pass parameters into another screen with react navigation, the second screen will get give "cannot read property 'params' of undefined". I am using react tabs navigation and my code is based on https://github.com/expo/expo/tree/main/templates/expo-template-tabs.
index.jsx:
navigation.navigate('(tabs)', {screen: 'screen2', params: {data: 'test'}})

screen2.jsx:
export default function ScreenTwo({ route }) {

  console.log(route.params.data)

  return (
    <ThemedView
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
      }}
    >
      <ThemedText type="title">{route.params.data}</ThemedText>
    </ThemedView>
  );
}

I have tried using the useRoute hook to access the params object and it logged undefined.
Edit:
I changed
navigation.navigate('(tabs)', {screen: 'screen2', params: {data: 'test'}})

to
navigation.navigate('(tabs)', {screen: 'swimmer', data: 'Hello'})

and I still get TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined

I was able to fix it by using the useRoute hook like so
const route = useRoute();

console.log(route.params.data)

index.jsx
navigation.navigate('screen2', {data: 'test'})


Documentation doesn't mention wrapping parameters in params, when you send these parameters. I would write:
navigation.navigate('(tabs)', {screen: 'screen2', data: 'test'});

screen2.jsx can stay as is.

After changing that line in my code it still gives TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined.

Yeah. After the update changing it from
export default function Screen({route}: {route: RouteProp<AuthenticationNavigatorListBase, "screen">}) {}

to
const { params } = useRoute<RouteProp<AuthenticationNavigatorListBase, "screen">>();

works
